# Highslide JS- trouble loading previous settings into Editor

Tags: highslide

Hello Highslide People.

I've ran into this issue before and Hilde helped me solve it in this older post: http://www.highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=19754

I am trying to update a Highslide JS gallery on my site and add 2 new images.  (The gallery and the editor have not been used in the past 30 days).  To do this, my method has been this:

- load previous gallery settings into the editor from the highslide/editor-config.txt file
- upload my new images that I'd like to add to the gallery and use the editor to generate my HTML (with captions) for the new images
- download (NOT upload to FTP) the Highslide folder from the editor and then add the sized large and thumbs images to the existing Highslide>Images folder in my root
- manually add the HTML for the new images to my Highslide JS (not sure if that's the right terminology there)

Problem is that I can't get past the first step.  I get an error in my browser that it is unable to process the request because the URL is too long OR it goes to the Editor start page and when I click on the "Get started and don't show this again" link it doesn't do anything.

The last time I ran into this issue, Hilde indicated that there was a problem with the Editor and she was able to send me a link that worked.

Appreciate any help in finding out what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately our developer hasn’t been able to fix this problem yet. You can however remove the part that breaks the link to the Editor yourself.

Open the editor-config.txt file. Locate these two parts of the link: `+%22userdir` and  `jpg%22],` 
Delete `+%22userdir` everything between, and this: `jpg%22],` Make sure that you don’t have space between `,` and `+` in the link. 
Now your link should be ready for the [Editor](http://highslide.com/editor/).